# Is it legal to sell a drawing/painting of copyrighted characters?

Tags: drawing, copyright

For example, if I complete a drawing of Ryu from street fighter or Naruto is it legal to sell it online?

Comment: [Is it okay to use depictions of cartoon characters in an iPhone app?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/11020/8708)

Answer (score 1):

Copying someone else's copyrighted work for your own profit it universally considered copyright infringement*. So no, it is not legal.

Is it done? All the time. Will you get sued if you do it? You may, you may not.

*-though there are exceptions in the cases of fair use.